# HorizontalScrollview is not working android

Tags: android, xml, horizontalscrollview

I can't swipe to the right , The horizontalscrollview is not working.

I provided the preview of the XML below, I don't have java codes so that i only provided XML codes.

Problem: i have 5 buttons in the top of Google map fragment, i can't reach the 5th button because the horizonalscrollview is not working.

Here is the preview of the xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jBuE.jpg

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <HorizontalScrollView

        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#BEFFB6"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Building 1"
                android:id="@+id/p1"
                android:onClick="b1"
                android:layout_above="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Building 2"
                android:onClick="b2"
                android:id="@+id/p2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Building 3"
                android:onClick="b3"
                android:id="@+id/p3"
                android:layout_above="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Building 5 "
                android:id="@+id/p5"
                android:onClick="b5"
                android:layout_above="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="P.E center"
                android:id="@+id/p4"
                android:onClick="pecenter"
                android:layout_above="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="380dp"

        android:layout_height="450dp"
        tools:context="com.sumo.traffic.traffic"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using static dimensions for containers' widths, so the container are shown partially off the screen. You have to set relative widths. In this case, if you want to have the `ScrollView` large as the screen, you have to set the value `match_parent` to the attribute `android:layout_width` of the first `RelativeLayout`, the `LinearLayout` inside and the `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#BEFFB6">

            <!-- content -->

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- fragment -->

</RelativeLayout>
```